# Who is using React + mobx + react-router-v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, mobx

I'am new to React and during my "self-learning" process I discovered Redux. Nice! Then, React-router-v4. Nice too!!

Then, I discovered how to mix redux and react-router-v4, a little bit tricky, but it works.

Last week, I also discovered mobx and I love it. I like its simplicity compared to redux. But I wonder if somebody is using it with react-router-v4 because I did not find much tutorials on the web that talk about this mix of technologies.

Any feedback or advice?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Consider not using mobx to control or change routes, leave it to router itself. In this case mobx is for state and router is for routes, unless you have very complicated routes (but i dont really see a scenario with mobx controlling routes state).

Comment: Ok, so I don't need libraries like https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router ?

Comment: If you gonna keep them separated you dont need it.

Comment: I used mobx and router v.4 in my simple to-do app, you can check it if you want https://github.com/spiderpoul/react-to-do

Comment: I've had success with them together. The only "gotcha" is to use the `@withRouter` decorator on any "routed components" that are observers. I actually found the documentation for this a little tricky but the implementation once I understood was dead simple.